# OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, resolution=null}]

Tags: java, android

I want to display location autosuggestions but getting RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error but I have not exceeded my limit. I have also checked my google console it is not showing any message of limit exceeded.

Here is my code for PlaceAdapter.java:-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PlaceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;


    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds,
                             AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    mResultList = getPredictions(constraint);

                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }


    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                            mBounds, null);

            // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting place predictions: " + status
                        .toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");
            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getFullText(null)));
            }
            // Buffer release
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected.");
        return null;
    }

    class PlaceAutocomplete {

        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my xml file:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".ToFromO9Activity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:hint="Enter Place Here" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Selected Place:"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/select"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Code for ToFromO9Activity.java class:-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

public class ToFromO9Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteTextView;
    private TextView mNameView;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_from_o9);

        mAutocompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setThreshold(3);
        mNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ToFromO9Activity.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();

        mAutocompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();

            mNameView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAddress() + ""));


        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(TAG, "Google Places API connected.");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

I have checked my API key it is right. It is also giving NETWORK_ERROR.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience there is nothing to do with code. It's all about enable billing with Credit card and don't use debit card. Clear warnings from console. Refresh api key and try.

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue. It worked after enabling payment.

Comment: Thank You for your reply! Can you tell it cuts money without you being informed?

Comment: I dont have that specific experience in google console. But my understanding is they want credit card for auto detect.. But they always keep you posted my mail. You have to watch the usage always.

Comment: @GaneshKanna its working fine on web but not in android app yesterday, and its started working fine now? why it is happening so?

Comment: @Nbn I think may be  you have exceeded you daily Quota ..Thats why it worked next day ?

Answer (score 1):

For my case I had to migrate to the new *places SDK*.

**Deprecated :** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places`

**New one :** `com.google.android.libraries.places:places`

Source from **Google API Console** who are explaining that if you get `PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` maybe you have to migrate to the new SDK.

**Image Source :** [Picture from Google API Console (PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loqRi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must first migrate to AndroidX (if your project isn't using it already), and then migrate to the new version of Places SDK.

If you are seeing "**Can't load**" or '**9005 PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED**' errors in your Android app, your app may be using a deprecated version of the Places SDK for Android or iOS. Find migration guides for [Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration) to begin using the new Places SDKs.

NOTICE: Version 2.0.0 and later of the Places SDK for Android are dependent on AndroidX. Beginning with this version, the old support library will no longer be supported. In order to retain compatibility, you must migrate your projects to use AndroidX.