# error status:PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

Tags: android

I am using autocomplete text view with `googleapi` but I am getting this error:

> "PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"

Could anyone tell me what should I do now. I just want to know the error please tell me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OperationException\[Status{statusCode=PLACES\_API\_RATE\_LIMIT\_EXCEEDED, resolution=null}\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760602/operationexceptionstatusstatuscode-places-api-rate-limit-exceeded-resolution)

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible scenario:

1. You are calling the API too many times. Users with an API key are allowed 1000 requests per 24 hour period.
2. You are using a deprecated version of the Places SDK for Android as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing .